# Sizing child div within a parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need some help sizing a child div within a parent. The issue I'm facing is that my child div will resize based on the number of elements within the div, but I want each div to be the same size. The is with the .container. If my array returns all 6 items then there are no issues. However, if my array returns less than 6 items then each {styles.object} will be resized based on how much space is the container. Normally, if less than 6 items are returned each item will be bigger and take up more space. But, I want my objects to be all the same size even if less than 6 items are returned.

```
    var textContainer = <div className={styles.text_container}>
    <div className = {styles.text}>Experts</div>
    <span className={styles.view}onClick={() => handleNextClick()} >View More</span>
    </div>
    var displayData = <div className = {styles.container}>
            {array.slice(0,6).map((item,i)=>{
                return (
                    <>
                        <div className ={styles.object} key={i}>
                            <img className ={styles.img} src={item.image}></img>
                            <div className={styles.name}>{item.name}</div> 
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
            })}
</div>
return (
<>  
    {textContainer}
    {displayData}
</>

.text_container{
    display: flex;
    margin: 50px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 3vh;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
}
.text {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 20px;
    font: url('../../public/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf');
    letter-spacing: 0.24px;
    flex: 1;
}
.view{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 14px;
    font: url('../../public/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf');
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    margin: 50px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 28vh;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.object{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 22vw;
    height: 25vh;
    position: relative;
}
.name{
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 102%;
    text-align: center;
}
.img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The 1 million question here the following: If you have 5 or 3 elements, do you want them to have the same width as if there were 6 or should they stretch depending on the width of the window?

Comment: Same width if they were to have 6 elements. not stretched.

Comment: I figured it out. Set flex-grow: 0 so it doesn't take up extra space and instead of defining width set flex-basis to desired width.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-width & max-width on the child elements